# jQuery Nested Plugins Selector Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like the ability to nest one plugin within another. However my selectors are too aggressive and keep retrieving the elements for the nested plugin aswell.

For example given the following HTML:

```
<div class="my-plugin">
    ...
    <div class="my-plugin">
        ...
        <button class="select">Select</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following code to create the plugin:

```
$(function() {
    $('.my-plugin').myPlugin();
});
```

When I say the following (within my plugin):

```
// element is the element the plugin is attached to
$('.select', element);
```

This will retrieve the select element from the nested plugin within the outer plugin but I'd like it not to. Also I'd like to do the same when attaching click events. For example the following code should only attach the click event in the nested plugin and not within the outer plugin.

```
element.on('click', '.select', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

I hope I've explained that clearly. I'd appreciate if someone could show me how my selector can be improved to handle this. Thanks

Comment: Could you wire up a jsFiddle with the problem?

Comment: Could you include an example of there the `.select` element you indeed want to target would be located? Would they only be direct descendants of the plugin element or would the solution need to account for them being nested beneath some other html structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, selectors work against the context they're given. If you tell jQuery to search a div, it will search everything in that div for what it's looking for. It's just how jQuery works.

If you want to exclude the inner plug-in, give it an id and exclude it using .not(). Or you could give it a class or data-* attribute as well. We just need something to tag it as "do not include".

So, do this:

```
$('.select', element).not('#mySecondPlugin');
```

or:

```
$('.select', element).not('.mySecondPlugin');
```

or:

```
$('.select', element).not('[mySecondPlugin="true"]');
```

This selector will select everything within your outer element EXCEPT the inner one and its contents.

And finally:

```
$('.select', element).not('[mySecondPlugin="true"]').on('click',  function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Cool! Or: $('.select:not(".my-plugin .my-plugin .select")', element);

Comment: Thanks this is my preferred approach. I think the cleanest solution is to attach a data attribute when the plugin is initialized. Also thanks @Seza for the additional advice.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe it's not the fastest selector you'll get, but at least you don't have to change your HTML.

Comment: @nfplee Awesome. Happy to help. So, how's the whole bounty thing work? I've never been part of a question with one before. Just curious.

Comment: @Yatrix I have to award it to the person I think deserves it (you). However I have to wait 5 more hours before I can do it. I think it would fall back to you if I forgot to award it anyway as yours is the selected answer.

Comment: @nfplee I just looked it up. If you don't award it, I'll get half as long as I have 2 upvotes and you'll still lose all of the points you put up for the bounty. I'll pretend that makes sense to me. You would think accepting an answer would award the bounty automatically. Eh, whatever. =)

Comment: @Yatrix oh right. Thanks for the heads up. Yeah you'd have thought that lol.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I recommend.

At initialization:

```
    $(element).addClass('my-plugin');
    var $selects = $(element).find('select')
                   .not( $(element).find('.my-plugin select') );
```

You would have to make sure that the `element` and `$selects` variables are accessible to all functions in the plugin.

On the note about `on()`, here's what I would suggest:

```
    element.on('click', '.select', function(){
        // see if the closest .my-plugin is the matching element, and not 
        // a child plugin
        if ( ! $(this).closest('.my-plugin').is( element ) )
            return;
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I think this is what he is already currently doing. This would target elements inside the nested plugin that he wants to omit.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what you mean, but I just realized a problem. I edited the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I may use parts of this solution when doing live binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the first occurrence of a selector from an element. So you could target the nested div with `#('.select').closest('.my-plugin')`.

Using [jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var myPlugin = this;//or whatever is representing your plugin jQuery object.
var selectsYouWant = $('.my-plugin .select').filter(function(index){
    if(this.closest('.my-plugin') === myPlugin) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. This saves me from adding a data attribute but the selector is not quite as clean as the one in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand events. When you click on the element, event bubbles up the DOM tree. You need to stop propagation, so that it would not reach outer plugin handler. Depending on the logic you may also need to prevent default action:

```
element.on('click', '.select', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Also, not sure what is the logic inside plugin, but you can filter out inside items:

```
var button = $('.my-plugin').find('.select').not('.my-plugin .my-plugin *');
button.css('color', 'red');
```

See: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryurN/)

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much the same as my selected answer but their's came first :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to start outside of your first plugin:

for example:

```
<div class="plugin-wrapper">
    <div class="my-plugin">
        ...
        <button class="select">Select</button> //We want this one
        <div class="my-plugin">
            ...
            <button class="select">Select</button> //Without this one
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then be able to use something like `$('.plugin-wrapper > .my-plugin > .select')` which would get ONLY the first `.select` without the second. Which I believe is what you are trying to accomplish

For the onclick

```
$('.plugin-wrapper > .my-plugin > .select').on('click', function () {
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it wouldn't be able to target .select elements that were grandchildren of the plugin element while not being descendants of a different .my-plugin element.

Comment: @ogc-nick that is true, the assumption would be that the `.select` would be a direct child.

Comment: Again as mentioned in my comment to sh0ber. This suffers from the problem @ogc-nick has already pointed out. Thanks anyway.